# Need help regarding JavaScript & AJAX

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to add an event listener to my delete buttons. Once clicked, I want to create a DELETE request to my nodeJS backend which will delete that todo item from firebase realtime database via firebase Admin API. But I am stuck. I don't know how to send a delete request from the frontend to the backend.
Also, I don't know how to send an AJAX request from JS to the server.

It's my first nodeJS app & I need to complete it to learn more about nodeJS.

[image: Image included to my frontend so you'll get my question more quickly.]

```
let deleteBtns = document.querySelectorAll("[data-delete-btn]");
console.log(deleteBtns)

deleteBtns.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/todo',
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result)
            }
        });
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you provide info about your backend endpoint for deletion? Is it a DELETE request to `api/todo/:id`?

Comment: Check the browsers inspect(debugger), is the request being sent?

Comment: It is a DELETE request to "/todo". From AJAX I am sending a Delete request to the same URL "/todo but with query string to identify which item to delete.

Comment: Btw i figured it out. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

you have provided very little details of code!!!

the way i have  solved this with java script   is below

```
//Delete task.
var deleteTask=function(){
        console.log("Delete Task...");

        var listItem=this.parentNode;
        var ul=listItem.parentNode;
        //Remove the parent list item from the ul.
        ul.removeChild(listItem);

}
```

link to complete code is below

https://codepen.io/franklynroth/pen/ZYeaBd

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough details. Actually, all I want to do is send an AJAX delete request from JS to the backend. There, nodeJS will catch that delete request & perform an action.